# React, SignalR Best Practice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, signalr

I have a react app that uses SignalR to be notified when a new image is available.
I tried to simplify it as much as possible.
I would like to move whole signalR into some sort of context or reducer, but cannot get my head wrapped around it.

This works but seems fragile and rigid.  It also appears to be calling the API serveral times before stopping and I would like to prevent that from happening.

My Question is how can I move my SignalR to a hook that gets the itnial card data and then is only called when it needs to be refreshed from a notification from the server.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { cardDataReducer, initialCapturedImages } from "../../reducers/reducer";
import { useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import { GetImages, CapturedImage } from "../../services/mongo";
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2'; // Grid version 2
import { setUpListener } from "../../services/signalR";
import { Container } from "@mui/material";

export function BaseMediaLayout() {
    const [cardData, dispatch] = useReducer(cardDataReducer, initialCapturedImages);
    
    const fetchData = React.useCallback(async()=> {
        const data = await GetImages(10);
        dispatch({
            type: 'fetched',
            capturedImageFetch: data,
            id: "",
            text: "",
            capturedImage: undefined
        })
        return data;
      }, [])

    const onSignalRNotice = () =>{
        fetchData();
        return true;
    };
      
    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
      }, [cardData.lastUpdated == null ? "" : cardData.lastUpdated.toString()]);

    

    const signalR = setUpListener(onSignalRNotice);

    return (
        <Container>
        <Grid>

        </Grid>
        </Container>
    )
}
```